# Super-columns in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, super-columns

I must do 5M (5 000 000) super-columns, or ~25M (5M * 5) regular composite-key columns.
Alternatively I need to use ordered partitioner.

What is exact downside of too many super columns? 
and why I should avoid them, 
because if i do composite keys, it is "home-made" super column, and all keys will be still there.

Answer (score 2):

Super columns are deprecated and will be replaced ultimately by composites.  This is reason enough to avoid them.  Plus there is a performance hit with SCs, and the codebase for them is generally not as well traveled.

Comment: Super columns are NOT deprecated.

Comment: I've had multiple DataStax devs refer to them as deprecated, and this [issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-3237) alludes to this as well.

Comment: [why-are-super-columns-in-cassandra-no-longer-favoured](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11915255/why-are-super-columns-in-cassandra-no-longer-favoured)