# what are the limitations of using DataStax cassandra (windows version) as DB?

Tags: performance, ssis, cassandra, limit

Our team has decided to use a no-sql database - Cassandra - and will integrate it with .Net technology. Before starting our project we need the help of other specialist in Cassandra. Our important question is what are the limitations of DataStax Cassandra with respect to performance, maintenance, complex queries, material views, transactions, import / export and reporting?

As a test I get that

- import and copy command do not work in Windows
- sstable loader does not work in Windows
- cannot define supercolumn

SSIS can solve some import problems but beside these problems what other limitations does Datastax Cassandra have on Windows?

Comment: Super columns are out-dated and shouldn't be used: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11915255/why-are-super-columns-in-cassandra-no-longer-favoured

Comment: i know that supercolumn is depracated and use composite column in return. i said i reach to these limitations on Windows Datastax community version. is anybody know other limitations  that i dont point to.